# Office 365 Distribution Group not showing in Sharepoint Permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, active-directory

Any idea why only some of my AD groups are showing in SharePoint? I have a Sales group that is in AD AND Office 365 groups, but not showing in SharePoint. I want to add that group to one list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use distribution groups as securable objects in SharePoint. It must be converted to a mail enabled security group. This has been the case for nearly a decade.